# Unable to .append() HTML to already existing element

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Having an issue that I just cannot get my head around. Trying to input some HTML into an already existing block on a website I am building but can only get the code to work in the console but not within the the JS input field within the theme.

Website is jck-sports.co.uk and on the homepage on the New Lines section if you run the below JS in DevTools:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var link;
    var btnStart = "<div class='product-actions'><div class='product-actions-inner'><div class='product-action product-action-add-to-cart'><a class='button product_type_variable add_to_cart_button' href='" + link + "' rel='nofollow'>Select options</a></div></div></div>";

    $(".new-lines-homepage-container .wvs-pro-product").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('product-hover-style-info-bottom','product-hover-button-shape-square','product-hover-act-position-center','product_title_type-full','product_icon_type-line-icon');
        link = $(this).find(".product-thumbnail-inner > a").attr("href");

        $(this).append(btnStart); // Will only show "Select options" and no other HTML in the DOM

        console.log("<div>test</div>"); // Will only show "test" with no DIV's.
    });

});
```

It will add the button into the correct place but when adding this code into the theme like I do will all my other JS it doesn't work and only adds the "Select Options" text but strips out all the other HTML, even if I console log some HTML as a string it wont either. Any ideas on how to rectify this or am I missing something?

The doc ready needs to be in there as per the theme, else it wont load any Jquery.

Comment: can you add that in your website and let me know

Comment: I have added this to the site now for you to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

**First**: Make sure your output JS have the HTML structure you want. In your case, I see the variable only have the plain "Select options" text as screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

**The second**: The `link` variable is updated in every loop but `btnStart` will not be updated and always have the `undefined` link. You should fix your code's logic too.

Comment: This is not the code in question. The code in question is at the top of the page. This is commented out for a reason but I have added the code to the website now so you can see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Well sort of, the issue lies with the built in custom JS field as installed another plugin to manage my JS and it works as it should.